# CSS a:hover not working for me in doctype

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

suddenly the a:hover isn't working and I have been trying to work on a solution for 8 hours, pls if someone could help that would be really good. oh and please ignore the size of the links I didn't make it responsive yet.

when i hover over a link the background color should change although it doesn't. a couple of days ago the a:hover was working for me,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //animation for slides
 $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 4000);
 //end of animation
 

});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
@import url("webfonts/drugulinclm_bold/stylesheet.css");

/* CSS Document */






nav{
 
 z-index: -1;
 
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #334450;
 height: 150px;
 padding: 20px 0px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
}
nav ul{
 
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 
 
 
 margin: 40px auto;
 padding: 5px 0px 5px 30px;
}
nav li{
 display: inline;
 list-style: none;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

a{
 display: inline;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 50px;
 vertical-align: text-bottom;
 color: black;
 background-color: #C5FFFC;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 padding:20px 40px
 
}
#speciala{
 background-color: orange;
}

#nav ul li a:visited{
 color: purple ;
}
#nav ul li a:hover{
 background-color: #3A98FC;
}
#speciala:hover{
 background-color: rgba(255,113,3,1.00)
}

#logo{
 z-index: 2;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 350px;
 max-height: 350px;
 right: 0;
 margin-top: 89px;
}


header{
 position: relative;
 width: auto;
 
 height: auto;
}
footer{

}
main{
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}
#title{
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 
}
#line{
 
  
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: -280px;
}
h2{
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 top: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 48px;
}
body {
 background-color: #FFF9E3;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: "drugulinclm bold";
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}
.important-title {
 text-align: center;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 72px;
}
#slideshow { 
  width: 1500px; 
    height: auto; 
 display: block;
    margin: auto; 
    position: relative; 
   
    padding: 0px;

    
}
#slides{
 position:absolute;
 display: block;
 transform-origin: center;
 width: 1500px;
 height: 900px;
 
 
 margin: auto;
 top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>index.html</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>

 
<body>
 <header>
 <img src="images/Logo.png" id="logo" href="index.html"  alt=""/>
<nav id="nav">
 
     <ul>
 
 <li><a href="#">מנות ראשונות</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">בשרים</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">פחמימות</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">דגים</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">קינוחים</a></li>
 <li><a id="speciala" href="#">העלו מתכון שלכם</a></li></ul>
    
  </nav>
  
 </header>
 <main>
  <div id="title"><h2>Pasta With Meatballs</h2>
  
  <img id="line"src="images/decorative-clipart-fancy-3.png" alt=""/></div>
  
  <div id="slideshow">
   <div>
    <img id="slides" src="images/d87c1237-c3e2-401a-b26b-9afc323e503f.jpg" alt=""/> 
   </div>
   <div>
    <img id="slides" src="images/1.png" alt=""/> 
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </main>
 
 <footer>
 
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: an invisible element is overlaping .. check the slide you added

Comment: Your div id slideshow is overlapping the nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `z-index` of -1 on your `nav`.

Change it to:

```
nav {
    z-index: 1;
    ...
}
```

And it should be ok.